# .net core 2 with angular SSR NodeInvocationException: The Node invocation timed out after 60000ms

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I successfully deployed an SSR angular application with .net core backend, and it works perfectly in production for like ~24hrs and after that my application goes down with error NodeInvocationException: The Node invocation timed out after 60000ms.

and when I run `htop` on my machine,  I see that some node process that related to .net application (PID 46) is really taking lots of machine CPU without stopping ore calming down

[image]
   ##  ##

Node -v 
10.18.1

Angular -v
8.2.3

dotnet core v
2.2